# How to disable Gitlab's merge request message on push?

Tags: git, gitlab

I wish to update my branch `feat` with some changes applied on branch `dev`, then apply other changes from `feat` to `dev`. For that, I run the following command in a shell (the redirection of stdout to /dev/null might not be necessary, but I put it here to show what I tried):

```sh
(git checkout feat --quiet &&
git pull origin dev --quiet &&
git push --force-with-lease --quiet &&
git checkout dev --quiet &&
git merge feat --quiet &&
git push --quiet) > /dev/null
```

The idea is to keep the error messages if there are some, but otherwise to keep the commands silent. However, I still get a message printed in the console :

```
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for feat, visit:
remote:   https://... (link to remote gitlab instance to create a merge request)
remote:
```

The first push (with --force-with-lease option) works fine, however the second one still outputs the above message. Am I missing some command option here? Is it possible to silence the remote without redirecting the stderr?

Comment: what version of git are you on ?

Comment: version `2.29.2.windows.2`